# AJAX query inside directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that creates multiple form elements:

```
// Directive
app.directive('comboInput', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            imodel: '=',
            dmodel: '=',
            bmodel: '=',
            inputname: '@',
            integers: '=',
            decimals: '='
        },
        templateUrl: templatePath + 'combo-input.html'
    }
});

// Template
<select id="" ng-model="imodel" ng-change="bmodel=imodel+dmodel" ng-options="value for value in integers"></select>
<select id="" ng-model="dmodel" ng-change="bmodel=imodel+dmodel" ng-options="(value|fraction) for value in decimals"></select>
<input type="number" name="{{inputname}}" ng-model="bmodel">

// Usage
<combo-input inputname="width" bmodel="width" imodel="widthI" dmodel="widthD" integers="ints" decimals="decs"></combo-input>
```

This application's controller has a method to grab a price:

```
$scope.getProductPrice = function(){
    return $http.post('/customize/angular/getProductPrice', {
        sku: '$scope.sku',
        width: $scope.width,
        height: $scope.height
    }).then(function(response){
        $scope.productPrice = parseFloat(response.data).toFixed(2);
    });
}
```

I use this method on various parts of the form, typically by calling `ng-change="getProductPrice()"` on some form element; however, this does not work when calling it from the template.

I have tried a number of different answers I've found here on SO, but none of them work as expected (like infinite $http calls that run forever), or maybe if they do, the person submitting the answer provided no comments or other details on *why* the code works so I am unable to adapt to my needs. On top of this, various methods all use different techniques, some deprecated, so there is no consistency to figuring out what I need to do.

**How can I call `getProductPrice()` from my directive's template?**

---

Edit

I've created a Plunker to demonstrate the old value being passed to the `getProductPrice()` method.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1nRs26nTaSOztjvVyLYg?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You directive has an isolated scope (`scope: {...}`) so it will not have access to the upper controller scope's variables and methods, such as `getProductPrice`.

What you can do is pass this method as a parameter to your directive:

```
app.directive('comboInput', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      imodel: '=',
      dmodel: '=',
      bmodel: '=',
      inputname: '@',
      integers: '=',
      decimals: '=',
      on-change: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: templatePath + 'combo-input.html'
  }
});
```

Which you then instanciate like this:

```
<combo-input ... on-change="getProductPrice()"></combo-input>
```

And then you just need to call `scope.onChange()` from your directive to call this function that has been bound to the `on-change` attribute.

Or you can even directly bind it to the built-in `ng-change`:

```
<input ... ng-change="onChange()">
```

**UPDATE**: if you want to pass specific parameters for this call, you can simply add them in the method signature:

```
$scope.getProductPrice = function(width, height) { ... }
```

And also in the directive binding:

```
<combo-input ... on-change="getProductPrice(width, height)"></combo-input>
```

And then all you need to do is call `onChange` with these parameters. If you write that in the HTML, it is as simple as:

```
<input ng-change="onChange(width, height)">
```

(Making sure that `width` and `height` are in your directive scope obviously so it can be used from the HTML).

If you want to call that from the code, either `width` and `height` are already in your scope, in which case you only need to call `scope.onChange()`. However if they are not, you can add these parameters just for this call with this specific syntax:

```
scope.onChange({width: value1, height:value2})
```

---

Another approach is to make this Ajax method a service instead of a controller function. By injecting the service in your directive, you could directly call `myService.getProductPrice()`. The advantage of the parameter binding is that you can reuse your directive with a different behavior, but if it will always call that function then a service is prefered.

Comment: I had thought it should be this simple, I don't understand why so many other answers make everything so convoluted; however, with this example, the request parameter is always the old value and not the new value.

Comment: what is the request parameter exactly? is it `"$scope.sku"`? this seem to be a constant string in your example.

Comment: PS: the convoluted answers you found were probably about binding an `$http` call direcrtly to a watcher such as `{{getProductPrice()}}` (hence executed on every digest cycle). This used to be supported but not anymore as the call was being done all the time (and was killing servers). In your case, you execute the call only at specific events (`ng-change`) so it doesn't matter.

Comment: The ajax params for `$scope.width, $scope.height` are submitting the old values instead of the new value after the change is fired. Also, I assumed `on-change` is a typo where you add it to the iso-scope, and changed it to `onChange` instead.

Comment: @pspahn ok I have updated my answer with how to pass parameters to an expression bound to a directive

Comment: Yeah it is still submitting the old value even when passed as a parameter. When used from a form element outside the directive, everything works as expected. I will keep plugging at this and update as necessary

Comment: From the function make sure to use the parameter `width` and not `scope.width`. Use `alert` or `console.log` to debug where the parameter becomes wrong.

Comment: Added a plunker to demonstrate old value being passed.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's because `ng-change` is triggered before the scope is actually updated (yeah that's weird). A clean solution is to use a watcher instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uo8VnzRuwj2vClGeYXs4?p=preview

Comment: And if you're interested, the other way to solve that without a watcher is using `onChange({width: bmodel})` as shown here http://plnkr.co/edit/olQQYuCvNRaof6Dma4I7?p=preview (or you can replace `width` by anything else like `myVariable` and use that in your binding `on-change="getProductPrice(myVariable)"`)

Comment: AHA! The watcher seems to be perfect. The other option I don't think will work since each instance of the template will need to know about other instances ... the beer I owe you is located in Denver. Send me a message to collect. =)

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared the scope oft your directive to be a new one, just the entries that you declare are bound between this scope and the outer (with your method in it).

You can either pass the function to the directive scope using the scope hash of the directive definition object or you add another ng-controller with the same controller inside the directive.